# Sending lines in a logfile to a remote server in "real time" (no syslog)

Tags: file, logging, elastic-stack, graylog

I am sorry to bother with this, but I am out of ideas.

Situation:

I have servers with software installed (the same one actually, serveral times). Each of those installations produce several logfiles.
There is no syslog option available. And even if it was, there are so many log files I need to distinguish, I'd run out of facilities.
The logfiles are named the same in each installation (however, renaming them on the destination server I want to send them to, is not an issue)

Goal/what I am looking for:

I need a software to transfer all log entries of each logfile made by those software installation in "nearly" realtime (like syslog) to another server to store them as "raw data" (files) and, if possible, additionally to other places (like Graylog, ELK, etc.) at the same time.
I cannot rename or alter the logs on the source system. I can, however, configure the destination system with folders and such as I like (so I can distinguish the logs from each installation).

Is there a software that might help me achieve that?

Thank you for your help
best regards
scheuri

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat), [NXLOG](https://nxlog.co/products/nxlog-community-edition), or basically any other log shipper reading from (text) files for this.

If you're using Graylog, you should also take a look at the [Graylog Collector Sidecar](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.3/pages/collector_sidecar.html).